# Change B2C Local Account Signup from Email to Username for existing app

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an app that is registered in Azure B2C with with B2C policies. I want to change using from using email local account to username (under identity providers) for my existing app. Will this break anything in my registration? I read that policies will no longer work. Is this process reversible? Is there anything I need to know before doing this? I need to check before heading down a path that might not be recoverable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the Azure AD Graph API to update the 'User' entity.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet